# Initialize arguments of two types

Tags: java, arguments, parameter-passing

I wrote a method that takes an argument of either `Taxi`type or `Shuttle` type. Here is it main idea :

```
public boolean requestPickup(Passenger passenger, Class<?> vehicleClass){
        Taxi taxi = scheduleTaxi();
        if(taxi != null) {
            taxi.setPickupLocation(passenger.getPickupLocation());
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me how can an arguments of two types be initialized?

Thanks

Comment: Java has no concept of attribute . Did you mean argument?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear at all what you want to accomplish. Please explain in more detail.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Taxi` and `Shuttle` and any supertypes?

Comment: Sorry @sharonbn I made a mistake I corrected it

Comment: What details you want to understand? @yole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection like this.

```
public boolean requestPickup(Passenger passenger, Class<?> vehicleClass){
            Object obj=Class.forName(vehicleClass.getName()).newInstance();

            if(obj instanceof Taxi){

                     //do taxi login
           }else if(obj instanceof Shuttle ){

                    //do shuttle logic
           }


    }
```

Comment: but .forName() is only for String type?

Answer (score 0):

Use interface Vehicle and extend two class from it named Taxi and shuttle. Now in your Signature pass interface as parameter. What that will do is you can pass all objects which extends that interface.

```
public interface Vehicle {

}

public class Taxi implements Vehicle {

}

public class Shuttle implements Vehicle {

}
```

now pass the Vehicle interface as parameter

```
public void requestPickup( Passenger passenger, Class<? extends Vehicle > Vehicle  ) {

 Vehiclec taxi = new Taxi();
 Vehiclec shuttle = new Shuttle ();
       .....

}
```

Comment: I cannot change the signature of the method, it's in the spec

Comment: use Class<? > Vehicle as parameter but it limits the scope.